# Gulp CLI - Are tasks run sequentially or parallel?

Tags: node.js, gulp

When running multiple tasks from Gulp CLI, are they run sequentially or parallel?

Example:

```
gulp taskA taskB
```

Does it run those in parallel or a series?

My brief test appears to indicate they do it in a series, but I was wondering if it was explicitly documented anywhere. I could not find any documentation that precisely said.

Comment: use with gulp 4, you can control as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They run in parallel. Gulp cli runs those tasks through [`gulp.start()`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/a54996c6a98acc000ebb310f89d7ca4bbacb9371/bin/gulp.js#L129) which actually uses the `orchestrator` library to run those tasks. See more about [`orchestrator.start`](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator#orchestratorstarttasks-cb) method:

> Note: Tasks run concurrently and therefore may not complete in order.
>   Note: Orchestrator uses sequencify to resolve dependencies before
>   running, and therefore may not start in order.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Glad I asked. My quick demo appeared to run in series which would have been a big problem if I made that assumption, since the first task sets a variable that all other tasks read. Thanks for providing the documentation as well... always great to have an official source.